# how do I get teams to work on ubuntu 220.04. uni say they dont support linux

Tags: microsoft-teams

teams wont work with the university login or personal email.
the blackboard works on google chrome. is there anything I can do?
password not accepted.

Comment: there's an existing client, or several I think, through snap.  Try "snap find teams" and then use `sudo` to install the `snap` package.

Answer (score 2):

Searching the Microsoft site will learn you that there is a client for MS Teams available for Linux, working also on Ubuntu.

Comment: ... but is being phased out in favor of a purely web based client.